# Predict time of next purchase

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, survival

I'm trying to build a model in R that will let me predict when a costumer will purchase a product again.  For example, the training data list customers who purchased bikes. I want to predict when these customers will purchase another bike in my store. However I don't know what kind of model can handle time and predict this kind of outcome. I thought about trying a *buy till you die* model, but this outputs the frequency of future purchases, and not when the next purchase will happen.

Comment: You could probably use a survival model. Instead of survival you are looking at the length of time until purchase.  A Poisson model where you count the number of days until the event might also be appropriate here.

Comment: What does your data set look like?

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Elma , i'm working on the same topic , i think you should collect all varaibles witch can affect customer purchase behaivour and after you doing a logistic regression (1/0). let me know more for  your topic